# WPF: Reusing control with slightly different call on ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a control, ActionRequiredControl.xaml that includes a combo-box with a list of enums. This control has ActionRequiredViewModel as it's DataContext, and the following call is used to populate the combobox:

```
    public IEnumerable<ActionType> Actions
    {
        get
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(ActionType)).Cast<ActionType>();
        }
    }
```

And the combo-box is as follows.

```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
   <Label>Action:</Label>
   <ComboBox Width="170" MinHeight="45"  Margin="5,0,5,5" Padding="5" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding Action, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Actions, Mode=OneTime}" 
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding IsUsed}"/>
   </StackPanel>
```

This control is used in two places currently (There is more to it than just the combobox) - however, I would like to re-use it in a third place, only have the "Actions" function return a different list of .

What's the best way to go about this? The only thing I can think of is creating a new class that inherits from ActionRequiredViewModel and overrides the Actions method.

Comment: That would be my preferred method. Or if your case is very simple you could pass the list in the constructor.

Comment: You are using `UserControl`, they are not *designed* to be inherited, etc. Though you can try (add *UserControl* to project and change its base class). In wpf we also have *custom control* (usually with `ControlTemplate` and `TemplateBinding`). Those can be *abstracted* from ViewModel completely (they belong to the view), which makes their re-usability not an issue anymore.

Comment: I'm extending the ViewModel, not the control.

Comment: What about using a base class for view model and then use [abstract properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3z1377.aspx) within it. So the derived classes will determine the functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution was the one I indicated in the question - I created a new class that inherited from ActionRequiredViewModel and overrode the "Actions" method to return a different list of enums.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating an additional ViewModel will be the simplest solution. 
I was in a similar situation some time ago, my first implementation (using MVVM light) was using two VMs, and registering both in the ViewModelLocator and providing a property for each:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ViewModel1>();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ViewModel2>();

public ViewModel ViewModel1Instance
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ViewModel1>();
    }
}

public ViewModel ViewModel2Instance
{
    get
    {
       return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ViewModel2>();
    }
}
```

And then in XAML:

```
<local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding ViewModel1Instance, 
    Source={StaticResource Locator}}" ...
```

However, to be a bit more flexible, I replaced this with another solution later, which provided better customization.

**I played a bit with your requirements and came to this solution:**

Creating a dependency property in the code behind of the user control as a proxy:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ComboBoxItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxItems",
            typeof(IEnumerable<object>), typeof(TestUserControl));


public IEnumerable<object> ComboBoxItems
{
    get
    {
        return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ComboBoxItemsProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ComboBoxItemsProperty, value);
    }
}
```

In the XAML of the user control:

```
...ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"...
```

In the main view model:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Items
{
    get
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(ActionType)).Cast<object>();
    }
 }
```

In the main XAML:

```
<local:TestUserControl ComboBoxItems="{Binding DataContext.Items, 
    Mode=OneTime, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
</local:TestUserControl>
```

This worked for me, but using `object` instead of the custom type is not the most elegant solution.

PS: This is my very first answer on SO, (and no questions yet from me...).

Since I used SO for many years as my primary source of tips and tricks, I thought I can *TRY* to give something back...

And of course, I admit: trying to answer is not the worst method of learning a new topic (and WPF is fairly new to me, so please don´t blame me for a suboptimal answer :-)